# Mouse events not fired after applying CSS

Tags: javascript, css, svg, mouseevent, reactjs

I'm working on app that uses SVG to draw Nodes (i.e. rectangles) that have Ports (i.e. circles) and Edges (i.e. path) between two ports.

I'm attaching `mouseup`, `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` callback to ports in order to draw the edges. These events are triggered but when I add the following style the `mouseup` is never called and `mouseenter` is not called at when entering but delayed thus cannot draw the edge!

```
.graph path {
  fill: none;
}
.graph .edge-bg {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}
.graph .edge-fg {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  transition-property: stroke-width;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

Here is the Port React component:

```
// A React element representing a node port    
var Port = React.createClass({displayName: "Port",
componentDidMount: function () {
    if(this.props.inport) {
        // if inport then listen for mouse up event
        this.getDOMNode().addEventListener("mouseenter", this.onMouseEnter);
        this.getDOMNode().addEventListener("mouseleave", this.onMouseLeave);
        this.getDOMNode().addEventListener("mouseup", this.onMouseUp);
    }else { 
        // if outport then listen for mouse down event
        this.getDOMNode().addEventListener("mousedown", this.onMouseDown);
    }
},
// handle mouse down event on this port
onMouseDown: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    emitter.emit('mouse_down', this.payload());
},
onMouseEnter: function(event) {
    console.log("mouseenter on port");
},
onMouseLeave: function(event) {
    console.log("mouseleave on port");
},
// handle mouse up event on this port
onMouseUp: function(event) {
    console.log("mouseup on port", this);
    emitter.emit('mouse_up', this.payload());
},
onPortRendered: function(event) {
    emitter.emit('port_onrender', this.payload());
},
// gives detailed information about this port
payload: function() {
    return {target: 'port', nodeId: this.props.nodeId, name: this.props.name, x: this.props.x, y: this.props.y};
},

render: function() {
    var port = [];

    // create a clip path to crop hide a portion of the circle
    var cliPathKey = randomKey();
    var rectProps = {key: randomKey(), x: this.props.x, y: this.props.y-5, width: 5, height: 5*2};
    if(this.props.inport) {
        rectProps.x -= 5; // shift the cut-off rectangle to the left
    }
    var rect = React.DOM.rect(rectProps, null);     
    port.push(React.createElement("clipPath", {key: cliPathKey, id:"cut-off-"+cliPathKey}, rect));    

    // create a circle
    var circleProps = {key: randomKey(), cx: this.props.x, cy: this.props.y, r: 5, fill:"gray", path:"url(#cut-off-"+cliPathKey+")"};
    port.push(React.DOM.circle(circleProps, null));

    // notify about the creation of this port
    this.onPortRendered();

    return React.DOM.g({key: randomKey()}, port);
}
});
```

I couldn't find the problem, any idea what's preventing these events from firing?

Comment: thanks for the hit, unfortunately it didn't help!

Comment: can you show the js too?

Comment: Could you create a JSBin which shows the problem?

Comment: Would be easiest to help if you dropped this in a jsfiddle (or which ever service you like), so we could see it in action.

Comment: I can't reveal the whole thing (i.e. the different react components) however I think it's a problem related to overlapping SVG elements where the Edge is on top of the Port when I release the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a `mouseup` listener on the SVG tag, it has been called but the event is not propagated down to the port!

And it looks like the target of the event is the Edge (i.e. path) and not the Port so I disabled the mouse events on the Edge as follows:

```
.graph path {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: none
}
```

As this is a temporary solution (as I need mouse events on the Edge for editting), I've end-up drawing the edge on mouse move events shifted from the mouse pointer coordinates.